# how can be added Mediaelement in WPF in windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, mediaelement

i cant find good ways for embedding a mediaelement in my Winform in C#. I have a PictureBox or Panel in Winform that should be loaded a UserControl in wpf. is this possible at all? if yes ,please give me a litte pseudocode. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control in WinForms to host WPF controls

From that page:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the ElementHost control for hosting the
    // WPF UserControl.
    ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
    host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    // Create the WPF UserControl.
    HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1 uc =
        new HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1();

    // Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's
    // Child property.
    host.Child = uc;

    // Add the ElementHost control to the form's
    // collection of child controls.
    this.Controls.Add(host);
}
```